# MongoDB - Collection with many dynamic attributes

Tags: mongodb, database-design, nosql

In my application i have to save a "descriptor" that define a particular entity, for example. All this entity have some fixed attributes and some variable attributes.

Because i come from RDBMS I'm struggling to understand how to model this data:

In a RDBMS i will:

- Create separate tables for each one of this collection (there are no other ways..)

In MonboDB, will be better to have separate collections too, or have just one collection and each document will have the fixed fields plus the dynamic ?

This is are some examples:

FIRST DOCUMENT

```
{
    "name": "entityName",
    "type": "entityType",
    "date": "the Date",
    "fieldA": "valueForFieldA",
    "fieldB": "fieldB",
}
```

SECOND DOCUMENT

```
{
    "name": "entityNameTwo",
    "type": "entityTypeTwo",
    "date": "the Date for Two",
    "fieldC": "fieldC"
}
```

So, first document have `fieldA` and `fieldB` and the second document have fieldC (so, no `fieldA` or `fieldB` - that are the dynamic attributes). Both document for are `descriptors`, but, with variables attribute

My question is:

1. Is a good idea to create a collection called `descriptors` and then store all the documents ? The kind of `descriptors` can be very large in terms of dynamic fields (for example, i can have 50/100 kind of documents, each of this have their own "variable" field)
2. Is better to create separate collections (like in a RDBMS) and each field looks like a column ?
3. Dont know :) Maybe there is a better solution that i dont know... (RDBMS background don't help...)

Sure, in a RDBMS there solution is simple (solution 1. , there are no alternative)

Thanks for your help in advice.

Comment: When designing a data model in noSql db, consider how applications will use your database. In other words, it depends on how you want to query.

Comment: typically my application will make query for the fixed attributes. The variable attributes will be used as "storage". You can image this like the fixed attributes are the key, so i will rarely access for a variable attribute

Comment: I think your design is sufficient for this problem and creating separate entity would decrease the performance and adds complexity.So, my vote goes to creating single entity.